# Refreshing BoldDays of TMonthCalendar manually?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, monthcalendar

I'm using Delphi7.

I know that I can use BoldDays in OnGetMonthInfo event of a TMonthCalendar to pass an array of days that I'd like to appear in bold.

My problem is that if a new calendar entry is saved, I can't call the OnGetMonthInfo event manually.

Using

```
  MyCalendar.Date:=IncMonth(MyCalendar.Date, -1);
  MyCalendar.Date:=IncMonth(MyCalendar.Date, 1);
```

will refresh the calendar and the bolded months, but under Vista and Windows7 this produces an annoying "rolling" effect of the calendar.

Is there a way to update it without the "special effect"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may force the refresh of the currently displayed calendars by sending the MCM_SETDAYSTATE message.

in addition to the code to respond to the GetMonthInfo event

```
procedure TForm1.GetMonthBoldInfo(month:cardinal):cardinal;
 begin
  ...
 end;

procedure TForm1.MonthCalendar1GetMonthInfo(Sender: TObject; 
            Month: Cardinal; var MonthBoldInfo: Cardinal);
 begin
  monthBoldInfo:=GetMonthBoldInfo(month);
 end;
```

you need some code to refresh when a calendar entry changes...

```
var DayStates: array[0..2] of integer;
....
DayStates[0]:=GetMonthBoldInfo(month-1);
DayStates[1]:=GetMonthBoldInfo(month);
DayStates[2]:=GetMonthBoldInfo(month+1);
SendMessage(MonthCalendar1.Handle, MCM_SETDAYSTATE, 3, longint(@DayStates));
```